# In Python, wow can you select the keys from a dictionary such that its values are below a set value?

Tags: python, dictionary, select, sum

```
mydict = {'09_B_L': 47, '09_B_R': 12, '09_F_L': 65, '09_F_R': 56}
```

I want to select the keys such that the sum of its values are < 140.

Thus, for instance:
47 + 12 + 65 < 140
but also
56 + 65 + 12 < 140

and thereafter from these selections I want to select the pair of keys of which the value sum is closest to 140.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Start by studying how to evaluate `combinations` of values that are `< 140`, remembering the keys which passed that test.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
How can I select the combinations of values that are <140?